# Solutions for a Multi-Tenant Platform using Django with Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, multi-tenant

I am Developing an eCommerce platform with Django. Currently studying the ways to implement Multi-Tenancy "Multi Stores for each Merchant".
The approaches I have encountered put me into a difficult position as the solutions are different and Each with its cons and pros.
I have found that Multi-tenancy-schemas, Containers and the implementation of a TenantID into all tables works for my case. My only concern is performance.

I know that the Containers Approach (One App containers + Multi Database Containers) requires a lot of processing power.

What about the Multi-tenancy-schemas vs TenantID ?
Thanks

Comment: which approach did you choose and how well did it work?

Comment: We used laravel php. We made an api for authentication and sub domains for each store. It was kind of a solution. But I didn't continue on the project. Not sure how that turned out with the team. But I believe the same approach can be implemented in django

Comment: Thanks for answering @Basel